# Which NoSQL DB to use for Fast Reads, always ordered by DateTime, and some filtering

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, cassandra, redis, nosql

I am new to NoSql, and therefore not 100% sure which NoSql DB will best suit my requirements:

- The NoSql DB is for the 'Read' side of my CQRS architecture.
- There will be a lot of reads.
- There will be lots of data (cant be stored in Redis in memory DB)
- The data will be stored as JSON. (id, title, description, dateTime, tags)
- The data will always be requested by giving it a date range (to match against dateTime property of the stored JSON) - and it has to always return sorted by that dateTime ascending.
- When requesting data by date range, Tags can also be specified so data can either be only related to these tags, or data related to these tags should be excluded
- In future, may be querying capabilities on title, description will also be required.

Based one what I have read about NoSQL DBs, I was thinking of using Mongo DB or ElasticSearch.

The main requirement is Fast Reads, Data will always be needed in DateTime Ascending order, and some filtering on tags.

Please let me know what NoSQL DB will best suite me for the above requirements.

---

Update:

The writes will be completely random i.e. the data inserted will be individual (not bulk) and will be of any dateTime.

Also, I am not looking for 'product recommendation' - If you guys can recommend NoSQL type DB (document type, key/value store type etc) and few options that I should consider - or which of the products will suit my requirements best. This is just to narrow down my research a little.

Comment: SO doesn't offer any product recommendations. If you have specific programming related question, please update your question. I'll recommend you to do your own research and choose whatever solution works better with your application.

Comment: Tell us more about the write side of architecture. Should your DB support random write? Or is it using just bulk writes?

Comment: @Saleem updated question with the note

Comment: @AliDehghani update question with 'Write side' details

Comment: Imo, that `querying capabilities` would be very decisive. If you need a very advanced querying mechanism, any lucene based search platform (e.g. solr or elasticsearch) would be better option. Otherwise, i personally would choose MongoDB. Anyway, Sharding and Replication is a well supported for almost any NoSQL datastore.